# Changing tab-completion for read builtin in bash

Tags: bash, readline, tab-completion, bash-completion

The current tab-completion while "read -e" is active in bash seems to be only matching filenames:

```
read -e
[[TabTab]]
abc.txt  bcd.txt  cde.txt
```

I want the completion to be a set of strings defined by me, while file/dir/hostname-completion etc. should be deactivated for the duration of "read -e".

Outside of a script

```
complete -W 'string1 string2 string3' -E
```

works well, but i cant get this kind of completion to work inside a script while using "read -e".

Comment: When you refer to "tab completion inside a script", are you using a text editor to write the script? I.e., this isn't at the bash prompt, but inside vim/emacs/etc.?

Comment: Did you run that completion command inside your script? Or just trust that it was set in the environment? (Does using `complete -E -W ....` help? The documentation makes it sound like order could matter, though it probably doesn't.)

Comment: @chrisaycock I think the OP means that `read -e` run from a script isn't using that completion.

Comment: Yes, i suppose i wasn't clear enough there. Just as Etan said, i was referring to the completion that happens while the user is prompted to enter something.

Comment: @Mustermann: I added a sample utility to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it seems like a reasonable request, I don't believe that is possible.

The existing implementation of the `read` builtin sets the readline completion environment to a fairly basic configuration before calling readline to handle `-e` input.

You can see the code in [`builtins/read.def`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def), in the [`edit_line` function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def#n1040): it sets [`rl_attempted_completion_function`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX361) to `NULL` for the duration of the call to `readline`. `readline` has several completion overrides, so it's not 100% obvious that this resets the entire completion environment, but as far as I know this is the function which is used to implement programmable completion as per the `complete` command.

With some work, you could probably modify the definition of the `read` command to allow a specific completion function instead of or in addition to the readline standard filename completion function. That would require a non-trivial understanding of bash internals, but it would be a reasonable project if you wanted to gain familiarity with those internals.

As a simpler but less efficient alternative, you could write your own little utility which just accepts one line of keyboard input with `readline` and echoes it to stdout. Then invoke `read` redirecting its stdin to your utility:

```
read -r < <(my_reader string1 string2 string3)
```

(That assumes that `my_reader` uses its command-line arguments to construct the potential completion list for the `readline` library. You'd probably want the option to present a prompt as well.)

The readline documentation includes [an example of an application](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC49) which does simple custom completion; once you translate it from the K&R function prototype syntax, it might be pretty easy to adapt to your needs.

---

**Edit:** After I looked at that example again, I thought it had a lot of unnecessary details, so I wrote the following example with fewer unnecessary details. I might upload it to github, but for now it's here even though it's nearly 100 lines:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>

static void version(const char* progname) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s 0.1\n", progname);
}
static void usage(const char* progname) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-fhv] [-p PROMPT] [-n PROGNAME] [COMPLETION...]\n", progname);
  fprintf(stderr,
          "Reads one line using readline, and prints it to stdout.\n"
          "Returns success if a line was read.\n"
          "  -p PROMPT    Output PROMPT before requesting input.\n"
          "  -n PROGNAME  Set application name to PROGNAME for readline config file\n"
          "               (Default: %s).\n"
          "  -f           Use filename completion as well as specified completions.\n"
          "  -h           Print this help text and exit.\n"
          "  -v           Print version number and exit.\n"
          "  COMPLETION   word to add to the list of possible completions.\n",
          progname);
}

/* Readline really likes globals, so none of its hooks take a context parameter. */
static char** completions = NULL;
static char* generate_next_completion(const char* text, int state) {
  static int index = 0;
  if (state == 0) index = 0; /* reset index if we're starting */
  size_t textlen = strlen(text);
  while (completions[index++])
    if (strncmp(completions[index - 1], text, textlen) == 0)
      return strdup(completions[index - 1]);
  return NULL;
}

/* We use this if we will fall back to filename completion */
static char** generate_completions(const char* text, int start, int end) {
  return rl_completion_matches(text, generate_next_completion);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  const char* prompt = "";
  const char* progname = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
  progname = progname ? progname + 1 : argv[0];
  rl_readline_name = progname;

  bool use_file_completion = false;

  for (;;) {
    int opt = getopt(argc, argv, "+fp:n:hv");
    switch (opt) {
      case -1:  break;
      case 'f': use_file_completion = true; continue;
      case 'p': prompt = optarg; continue;
      case 'n': rl_readline_name = optarg; continue;
      case 'h': usage(progname); return 0;
      case 'v': version(progname); return 0;
      default:  usage(progname); return 2;
    }
    break;
  }

  /* The default is stdout, which would interfere with capturing output. */
  rl_outstream = stderr;

  completions = argv + optind;
  rl_completion_entry_function = rl_filename_completion_function;
  if (*completions) {
    if (use_file_completion)
      rl_attempted_completion_function = generate_completions; 
    else
      rl_completion_entry_function = generate_next_completion;
  } else {
    /* No specified strings */ 
    if (!use_file_completion)
      rl_inhibit_completion = true; 
  }

  char* line = readline(prompt);

  if (line) {
    puts(line);
    free(line);
    return 0;
  } else {
    fputc('\n', rl_outstream);
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: The link to the example application is dead :(