# Emulate TAB key press in Bash script to autocomplete

Tags: bash, tab-completion

I have simple Bash script running command in Kubernetes, however I need autocomplete in one command to continue:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
printf "Available Kubectl contexts:\n\n"
kubectl config get-contexts -o=name | sort -n
printf "%s\n"
echo -ne "Select Kubectl context: "; read KUBE_CONTEXT
for I in $KUBE_CONTEXT ; do
    kubectl config use-context $KUBE_CONTEXT
done
echo -ne "Path to file containing Job ID list: "; read -e JOB_ID_LIST
printf "%s\n"
echo "Setting port forwarding to Prometheus POD in $KUBE_CONTEXT" ;
```

and this is where I need autocompletion as the pod name is different in each kubectl environment.

```
kubectl port-forward -n prometheus prometheus-prometheus-RANDOM_TEXT-RANDOM_TEXT 20001:9090
```

for instance:

```
kubectl port-forward -n prometheus prometheus-prometheus-6465c4df4c-4dvf7 8080:9090 &
```

Autocomplete works when I am typing it manually, but I want Bash to autocomplete it in the script. Is it possible?

Comment: No, see: [Changing tab-completion for read builtin in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34660459/3776858)

Comment: `read` can output a prompt, no need for `echo`. You should almost always use `-r` with `read`. `read -e` enables readline during input, which you've already got in your script. You can create your own completions using Bash's [programmable completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using interactive features of a shell in a script should be your last resort.

We can do without:
Let's first get all pod names in the namespace; then filter for your desired pod name.

```sh
podName=$(kubectl get pods -n prometheus -o name | grep "^pod/prometheus-prometheus-" | cut -d/ -f2)
```